# c# vsto calling exe , works only half of the times

Tags: c#, vsto, exe

Hello everyone and thank you for the help
I made a word Addin while clicking some of the buttons like upload file or login,c# calling exe to run
But for some reason, the exe does not work each time I try, only half of the time, and if I succeed, when I am trying to call the exe again for a different purpose, I failed (nothing happend)
one more thing, I need to get the output of the exe file.

the exe in the debug folder
the code below:

```
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName("Api_Layer.exe");
        processInfo.FileName = "Api_Layer.exe";
        processInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        Process proc = Process.Start(processInfo);
        List<string> output = new List<string>();
        while (!proc.HasExited)
        {
            output.Add(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Comment: Where do you placed the button, is it a ribbon button? Do you have set a debug point to your function to see that your button works as expected? Does the "Api_Layer.exe" output something and will "ReadToEnd()" return something?

Comment: Api_Layer return output, the button is inside a ribbon and I tried to debug the code, sometimes when I am getting to process. start nothing happens and I can't move on with the debug but I can click again on the button and start again the debug from the begining